# el-dialog working but need css to open from bottom to top with effect

Tags: html, css, element-ui

I have e;-dialog setup on button click and it is working, all i am trying to do is make sure it opens from the bottom and goes like 300px height and show comntents inside it and when i click outside or inside any element, it will hide

here is my code

css first

```
<style scoped>
  #Status {
    display:none;
  }
  #Status.active {
    opacity:1;
    display:block;
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
    background-color:#fff;
    text-align:left;
    animation-name:disappear;
    animation-duration:4s;
    animation-delay:3s;
    transition: all linear 0.3s;
    animation-fill-mode:forwards;
    border-radius:8px 8px 0 0;
    z-index:999;
    width:100%;
    height:120px;
  }
</style>
```

element ui code

```
<div @click="show = !show">

<el-dialog id="Status" :visible.sync="show" v-if= "show">
        <div>
          hello
        </div>
      </el-dialog>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just transition the height since it's fixed to the bottom:

```
<style scoped>
  #Status {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    bottom:0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #fff;
    text-align: left;
    border-radius: 8px 8px 0 0;
    z-index: 999;
    width: 100%;
    transition: height 250ms ease-in-out,
                opacity 250ms ease-in-out;
  }
  #Status.active {
    opacity: 1;
    height: 120px;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: but that css is covering the whole page and showing as greyed out back

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. If there's something else going on it's probably some other css or html interfering because what I posted works properly: https://jsfiddle.net/mpkeacjn/

Comment: yes, it works as simple css, but if we use el-dialog it is messing up

Comment: In the element ui documentation it looks like there's a fullscreen option you need to set to false: https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/dialog